# Javascript. Why this condition s[i+1] don't give an error "out of range"?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary

```
var romanToInt = function(s) {
  value = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i += 1) {
    symbols[s[i]] < symbols[s[i + 1]] ? value -= symbols[s[i]] : value += symbols[s[i]]
  }
  return value
};
```

This is an leetcode exmple, I am confused with this condition `symbols[s[i]] < symbols[s[i+1]] ?`,I don't understand why s[i+1] won't out of range? or it is out of range but considered as false?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of JavaScript ;-)

Comment: out of range means in javascript `undefined`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this? Have you checked whatever `s[i + 1]` contains?

Answer (score 6):

In javascript, arrays are objects, so there's no such thing as out of range in javascript arrays. Array indexes are stored as keys. If the index doesn't exists in the array, `undefined` is returned.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(typeof arr);    // output: "object"
console.log(arr[4]);        // output: undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1.
>
> **Using an invalid index number returns undefined.**

Emphasis added.

In your case, any comparison of `<` or `>` with a number and `undefined` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript arrays are just objects, and indexes are like keys, as for any other field.

You can witness Javascript behavior here:

```js
let a = [ 0, 1, 2 ];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   console.log(a[i]);
}

console.log("Same for other fields:")
console.log(a.foo);
console.log(a.bar);

a.foo = "hi!"

console.log(a.foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, arrays are declared without a fixed size. Hence s[i+1] won't be out of range, it will just be undefined. Hence the final output will be false.